# Azure LogicApp Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring

I have a LogicApp which runs for every 2 minutes. All runs in this LogicApp has failed between 4:45pm to 5:00pm.

[image: Runs]

when I check for the metric Run Failure Percentage under 'Metrics' in the Azure portal with time granularity as 15 minutes and aggregation as Average, it shows me Run Failure Percentage as 114.29% for time window 4:45 pm to 5:00 pm.

[image: metric average value]

My question is, how the metric value is calculated? shouldn't it be less than 100 for percentage?

Comment: Typical Microsoft :D